# 1 @Test() per class file. There are 2 class files. @Test method in the 2nd class file fails with null pointer exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

### Base class file:(With @Before method)

```
package casestudy.one;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Basetest2 {

    public ChromeDriver driver;



  @BeforeMethod()
  @Parameters({"Uname","Pword"})
  public void btest(String Uname, String Pword, Method method) throws InterruptedException, AWTException 
  {
      if(!method.getName().equals("f"))
      {

                driver.findElementById("ctl00_MainContent_username").sendKeys(Uname);
                driver.findElementById("ctl00_MainContent_password").sendKeys(Pword);
                driver.findElementByName("ctl00$MainContent$login_button").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                System.out.println(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                robot.mouseMove(1142, 173); // move to co-ordinate Location
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); 
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); // Left Mouse click - Release 
                robot.delay(10);
                String str=driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@class='login_info']").getText();
                System.out.println("Login is successfull ---" +str.substring(9, 15));
                String title =driver.getTitle();
                System.out.println("The title of the screen is " +title );

            }



  }


@AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod()
  {


  //driver.quit();    

  }

  @BeforeClass
  public void beforeClass() {
      System.out.println("This is for 'before' class");
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void afterClass() {
      System.out.println("This is for 'after' class");
  }

  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
      System.out.println("This is for 'before' test");
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
      System.out.println("This is for 'after' test");
 }
 @BeforeSuite()
 public void beforeSuite() { 
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://downloads.smartbear.com/samples/TestComplete10/WebOrders/Login.aspx");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    

}

  @AfterSuite
  public void afterSuite() {
      System.out.println("This is for 'after' suite");
      driver.close();
 }
}
```

---

### 1st class file(ie Mainttest1a) with 1 @ Test method ( This is running successfully in TestNG)

```
package casestudy.one;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Maintest1a extends Basetest2 {
         @Test()
          public void g() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
              /*Navigate to orders */   

                driver.findElementByLinkText("Order").click();
                WebElement test1 =driver.findElementByXPath("//select[contains(@name,'fmwOrder')]");
                Select dropdown = new Select(test1);
                dropdown.selectByValue("FamilyAlbum");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                WebElement toclear= driver.findElementByXPath("//input[contains(@name,'MainContent')]");
                toclear.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
                toclear.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                driver.findElementByXPath("//input[contains(@name,'MainContent')]").sendKeys("3");
                Thread.sleep(6000);
                driver.findElementByXPath("//input[@value='Calculate']").click();
                String str2 =driver.findElementByXPath("//input[contains(@name,'MainContent')]").getAttribute("value");
                System.out.print("The total quantity is " +str2);
                String str3 = driver.findElementByXPath("//input[contains(@id,'txtUnitPrice')]").getAttribute("value");
                System.out.println(" and the value for price is " +str3);
                //driver.findElementByXPath("//input[@value='Reset']").click();
                Thread.sleep(6000);
                String str4=driver.findElementByXPath("//input[contains(@name,'MainContent')]").getAttribute("value");
                String str5 =driver.findElementByXPath("//input[contains(@name,'Content$fmwOrder$txtTotal')]").getAttribute("value");
                System.out.println("The value of quantity and total are  " +str4+ " and " +str5);


                /*Address of the order*/

                String str6 =driver.findElementByXPath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/h3").getText();
                System.out.println("The header of this section is "+str6 );
                driver.findElementByXPath("//span[contains(@id,'RequiredFieldValidator2')]/preceding::input[1]").sendKeys("Rajesh");
                driver.findElementByXPath("//span[contains(@id,'RequiredFieldValidator3')]/preceding::input[1]").sendKeys("Engg Avenue , Nagar,Kolathur");
                driver.findElementByXPath("//span[contains(@id,'RequiredFieldValidator4')]/preceding::input[1]").sendKeys("Chennai");
                driver.findElementByXPath("//input[contains(@name,'fmwOrder$TextBox4')]").sendKeys("TamilNadu");
                driver.findElementByXPath("//input[contains(@name,'fmwOrder$TextBox5')]").sendKeys("600034");


                /*Enter the credit card details, Payment information*/

                String str7 =driver.findElementByXPath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/h3[3]").getText();
                System.out.println("The header of this section is "+str7 );
                List Radiobutton =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'cardList')]"));
                System.out.println(Radiobutton.size());
                driver.findElementByXPath("//input[contains(@name,'cardList')]").click();
                if(driver.findElementByXPath("//input[contains(@name,'cardList')]").isSelected())
                {
                    System.out.println("Visa card is selected");
                }
                driver.findElementByCssSelector("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$fmwOrder$TextBox6'][type='text']").sendKeys("3256468744450213");
            driver.findElementByCssSelector("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$fmwOrder$TextBox1'][type='text']").sendKeys("07/18");
            driver.findElementByLinkText("Process").click();
            driver.findElementByXPath("//a[contains(@id,'InsertButton')]/following::strong").getText();
            Screenshot obj2 = new Screenshot();
            obj2.scrnshot(driver);


            /* Navigate to View all orders */

            driver.findElementByLinkText("View all orders").click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            String innertext=driver.findElementByXPath("//table[@class='SampleTable']/tbody/tr[2]/td[9]").getText();
            System.out.println("          ");
            System.out.println("The presence of the order is confirme with zip code as  " +innertext);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            obj2.scrnshot(driver);
          }

      }
```

---

### 2nd class file(ie Maintest2a) with different @ Test method ---- This code is failing with Null pointer exception as below

---

```
PASSED: g
FAILED: f
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at casestudy.one.Maintest2a.f(Maintest2a.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

### *********

```
    package casestudy.one;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class Maintest2a extends Basetest2
{

    //public static ChromeDriver driver;

    @Test()
    public void f() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        /*Edit the order */
    driver.findElementByXPath("//table[@class='SampleTable']/tbody/tr[2]/td[13]").click();
    driver.findElementByXPath("//input[contains(@id,'fmwOrder_cardList_1')]").click();
    driver.findElementByCssSelector("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$fmwOrder$TextBox1'][type='text']").sendKeys("08/19");
    driver.findElementByLinkText("Update").click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

   // driver.get("http://downloads.smartbear.com/samples/TestComplete10/WebOrders/Default.aspx");
   String actualtitle = driver.getTitle();
   System.out.println("The title of the page is " +actualtitle);
    String innertext2=driver.findElementByXPath("//table[@class='SampleTable']/tbody/tr[2]/td[9]").getText();
    System.out.println("          ");
    System.out.println("The presence of the order is confirme with zip code as  " +innertext2);  
    Screenshot obj3= new Screenshot();
    obj3.scrnshot(driver);


}
}
```

Is this issue related to driver intialization of Selenium Webdriver (or) issue in variable scoping. Please help me what is the mistake i am doing.And what is the fix for this. I have also attached the TestNG xml below.

### *****Pls note, this is not a duplicate******

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="10">

  <test name="Test">
  <parameter name="Uname" value ="Tester"></parameter>
  <parameter name="Pword" value ="test"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="casestudy.one.Maintest1a"/>
      <class name="casestudy.one.Maintest2a"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: By using single-character method names and very generic class names, you're only hurting yourself in terms of readability and understandability - especially if you're asking other people for help. Also - consider copy/pasting in the smallest possible set of code that reproduces the error - much of the boilerplate stuff is irrelevant to your issue.

Comment: @Catchwa - I thought of explaining it clearly, with complete code,so that an expert can easily understand it.

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger to see what the instance variable `driver` is doing? What happens if you remove the first test in your suite? What happens if you swap their order?

Comment: @Catchwa, i have put the debugger and can see that driver is returning null. But, i have called the driver globally.So, am trying put changing the annotations and checking it.

Answer (score 0):

Well your problem is you initialized your driver instance in Basetest2 class, but your never used same instance to your Maintest2a.java class.

You have to do something like below in Maintest2a.java:

private WebDriver driver;

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    System.out.println("Setting up drivers...");
    driver = getDriver();
}
```

Now, your same driver instance which you have initialized in Basetest2 presents in Maintest2a.java as well.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, Let me check and come back.Appreciate your response.

Comment: you welcome. Go ahead and do let me know if you need any other help on it.

Comment: Did you checked it? I guess it should work after the changes I suggested.